# mod_rewrite, help me forward a page

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm sorry but I don't really completely understand how mod_rewrite works but I'd like to basically change the url:

/index.php?category=value1&video=value2

to be accessed via /value1/value2

could anybody tell me how to do this? thanks^^

Comment: Nothing, I just don't understand how it works and I figured a lot of you guys knew how it did. I havn't learned about this yet but I need it to continue on my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?category=$1&video=$2 [L]
```

The first line enabled the usage from the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

The second line is a [condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) which checks if there is a file with that name. If not continue with the next line.

The third one is a regular expression. The `^` markes the beginning and the `$` the end of it. The `/?` means that at the beginning should be a optional `/` (this depends on the server configuration). The `(.*)` meanes a range of chars which from 0 until n. The brackets meanes that there is a group which can be called as `$n` here as `$1` and `$2`.

Please note that [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) must be enabled in the server configuration.

Comment: Alright, it seems to work, thanks a lot, and for the explanation on what everything actually means ^^ thanks, i can mark it as solution in two mins

Comment: Depending on the use case, something like: ^/?([^/]*)/(.*)$ might be handy. It is quite propable, the the category will contain no slash, whereas the videoname could

Comment: Indeet you may note also that `[^/]` means one char exept the `/` which can appear multible times (with the `*`).

Comment: Hmh, i have a problem with the code you gave me, i currently use "RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/?$ displayvideo.php?category=$1&video=$2 [L]", however when i use it, the page won't load the css file for some reason. when I view the source it points to the correct path, and when i remove the rewriterule it works fine again, this is the site http://drudexflash.com/test1/test2

Comment: the css won't load on any other page either

Comment: This is normal in this case. We need to add a condition see my edit.

Comment: Awesome it works great, thank you ^^, what exactly does that line mean?